# tellg function returns 2 after taking 1 character

Tags: c++, c++17

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open("test.txt");

    char buffer;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "tellg: " << inputFile.tellg() << "   ";

        inputFile >> buffer;

        std::cout << "buffer: " << buffer << std::endl;
    }

    inputFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Inside the `test.txt`:

```
asdfghjkl
```

The output of this program is:

```
tellg: 0   buffer: a
tellg: 1   buffer: s
tellg: 2   buffer: d
tellg: 3   buffer: f
tellg: 4   buffer: g
tellg: 5   buffer: h
tellg: 6   buffer: j
tellg: 7   buffer: k
tellg: 8   buffer: l

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Which works as intended, but when I change the contents of `test.txt` to:

```
asdfgh  
jkl
```

(moved jkl to a new line)

The program's output becomes this:

```
tellg: 0   buffer: a
tellg: 2   buffer: s
tellg: 3   buffer: d
tellg: 4   buffer: f
tellg: 5   buffer: g
tellg: 6   buffer: h
tellg: 7   buffer: j
tellg: 9   buffer: k
tellg: 10   buffer: l

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I made that change to `test.txt` with the assumption of `\n` affecting the output in some way. But I don't understand how `tellg()` jumps from 0 to 2 and 7 to 9.

Is there any explanations for this behavior of `tellg()`?

Comment: Examine the file with a hex viewer. See if there's anything unusual at the start. Perhaps a BOM mark.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion downloading a hex viewer atm.

Comment: Open in *binary* mode if you need numbers that `tellg` returns to make sense. For text files, these numbers are usable as codes that let you return to the same position in the file, but you cannot do any sort of meaningful arithmetic on them.

Comment: https://im.ge/i/ObnnsT This is ```test.txt``` in hex view. But I couldnt make any sense of it.

Comment: Open the ```test.txt``` in binary mode? @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.

Comment: Yes exactly. Open `test.txt` in binary mode.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I tried it and now the output is ```tellg: 0   buffer: a
tellg: 1   buffer: s
tellg: 2   buffer: d
tellg: 3   buffer: f
tellg: 4   buffer: g
tellg: 5   buffer: h
tellg: 6   buffer: j
tellg: 9   buffer: k
tellg: 10   buffer: l```    tellg jumps from 6 to 9 instead of 0 to 2 and 7 to 9

Comment: You have a newline between h and j and perhaps some other whitespace. `>>` skips whitespace.

Comment: Some file streams will extract a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character from the stream to get the correct type. The editor you are using may silently encode a BOM marker into the file. Thus 0 ->2.  The newline character is causing the 7-> 9

Comment: I see, so I shouldn't rely that much on ```tellg()```'s return values or keep in mind that some exceptions might occur.